# Reversing legend and data order for geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe (df) as follows

| id | count | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | positive |
| b | 4 | negative |

I have been able to create a bar graph with this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=result, y=count, fill = id)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Example", y = "Frequency", fill = "Group") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Positive", "Negative"))
```

The resulting bar graph looks like this
[image]

However, I want the Positive to be on the left and i want group a to be blue. How would the modified code look like if i had multiple results (e.g., positive, negative, unknown, small)?

Comment: Just about every question on SO that includes the words "ggplot2" and "order", and usually "axis" or something closely related ... are resolved by the use of `factor`. The default action of ggplot2 is to order things by alphabetic ordering; to force it, do something like `df$result <- factor(df$result, levels=c("positive","negative"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character variables mapped to aesthetics (such as x, y, fill, color, etc) in ggplot are converted into factors, and are arranged in the order of the factor levels. Unless you pass a factor with the desired ordering of levels to the discrete scale, they will therefore be arranged alphabetically, since this is the default behaviour when factors are created.

So we simply do this to get the desired ordering:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(factor(result, c('positive', 'negative')), count, 
               fill = factor(id, c('b', 'a')))) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "Example", y = "Frequency", fill = "Group") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Positive", "Negative")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c('a', 'b'))
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but is there a way to also invert the colors? So a would be red and b would be blue.

Comment: @Coldgrad yes, as explained above. Change the order of the `id` factor to `c('a', 'b')` (this is its default order anyway - I specifically changed it because your question asked for group "a" to be blue)